# Store FirebaseListObservable in custom class

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am building a basic mobile app with Ionic 2 and Firebase. I am using AngularFire2 to access firebase from my app.

I am struggling on one particular point.

I want to persist my current user. So I created a User class:

```
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { DatabaseService } from '../providers/database.service';

export class User {

  uid: string;
  observableList: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(uid: string, user: FirebaseListObservable<any>) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.observableList = user;
  }

}
```

A UserService that allows me to accomplish all actions related to users:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
import { User } from '../app/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private _db: DatabaseService) {}

  getUserAsObservableList(uid: string): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    return this._db.getUserAsObservableList(uid);
  }
}
```

The DatabaseService getUserAsObservableList is designed as follows:

```
getUserAsObservableList(uid: string): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    let ref = '/' + this.base + '/users/' + uid;
    return this.af.database.list(ref);
  }
```

The data I am accessing in Firebase:
[image]

And in my component I do the following:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private _auth: AuthService, private _db: DatabaseService, private _user: UserService) {
        console.log('HomePage constructor called.');
        this.user = new User(this._auth.uid, this._user.getUserAsObservableList(this._auth.uid));
        console.log('User: ', this.user);
      }
```

Finally, in my html view the following code:

```
<h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>

    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of user.observableList | async">
       {{ item | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Gives the following output:
[image]

So then I tried to access the public node:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of user.observableList | async">
       {{ item.public | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And get the following:
[image]

What am I doing wrong in my code? More globally, am I using a wrong pattern here? Should I implement this a different way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that since you are retrieving the properties of the user as a list, you can't access them by using the key. You have two options to achieve what you want. You can either retrieve your users as Objects or you need to wrap a `*ngIf` around the data you want to display like so:

```
<span *ngIf="item.$key == 'public'">
    {{item | json}}
</span>
```

Comment: I tried the *ngIf wrapping and it worked, thanks ! As to your first suggestion, to retrieve user as an Object, you mean with FirebaseObjectObservable?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant